# What does AdapterView<?> mean in the OnitemClick() Method? What is the use of other parameters in it?

Tags: android, android-adapterview

```
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(HelloGridView.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The `<?>` indicates a Generic. Read more about them [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/generics/index.html).

Here is what the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html) says about the parameters:

**`onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)`**

> **parent**    The AdapterView where the click happened.
>
> **view**  The view within the AdapterView that was clicked (this will be a view provided by the adapter)
>
> **position**  The position of the view in the adapter.
>
> **id**    The row id of the item that was clicked.

The `AdapterView` could be a `ListView`, `GridView`, `Spinner`, etc. The question mark inside the angle brackets indicates that it could be any of them. This is called [generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html) in Java. You can use **parent** in code to do something to the whole view. For example, if you were using a `ListView` you could hide the whole `ListView` by the following line of code:

```
parent.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

The `View` refers to a specific item within the `AdapterView`. In a `ListView` it is the row. Thus, you can get a reference to a `TextView` within a row by saying something like this:

```
TextView myTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
String text = myTextView.getText().toString();
```

The **position** is the position of the **view** in the **parent**. For a `ListView`, it is the row number. The top row is position 0, the second row is position 1, the third row is position 2, etc. Note that if your `ListView` has a header view (like if you did `ListView.addHeaderView(View)`) then the header view would be position 0 and the actual rows would start their numbering at 1.

Sometimes **id** is the same as **position** and sometimes it is different. If you are using an `ArrayAdapter` or `SimpleAdapter` then they are the same (except in the case that there is a header view and then they are off by one). For a `CursorAdapter` (and consequently a `SimpleCursorAdapter`) the **id** returns the row id of the table, that is, `_id`.

Here are a few other good answers on this topic:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/9863279/3681880
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/12966006/3681880
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/24531354/3681880

Comment: How to get the id of `AutoCompleteTextView` using parent object?

Answer (score 0):

The ? means that the datatype is unknown and it can be any type.

Comment: You added the adapter and know the type - so simply typecast to get what u want.