# modified adapter does not call getView()

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

Using FirebaseUI code to make a `listview` adapter. It doesn't call `getView()` in the adapter, and nothing is displayed. Sending data seems to work fine.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;


import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.hqs.tart.adapters.firebase.FirebaseListAdapter;
import com.hqs.tart.adapters.firebase.FirebaseListOptions;
import com.hqs.tart.tabletoproleplaytool.R;
import com.hqs.tart.models.ChatMessage;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link GlobalChat.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link GlobalChat#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class GlobalChat extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    private FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessage> adapter;
    ListView listOfMessages;

    public GlobalChat() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment GlobalChat.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static GlobalChat newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        GlobalChat fragment = new GlobalChat();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }

        Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference()
                .child("chats")
                .limitToLast(50);
        FirebaseListOptions<ChatMessage> options = new FirebaseListOptions.Builder<ChatMessage>()
                .setQuery(query, ChatMessage.class)
                .setLayout(R.layout.fragment_chat)
                .build();

        /* adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessage>(options) {getActivity(), ChatMessage.class,
                R.layout.fragment_chat, FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference() */
        adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessage>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void populateView(View v, ChatMessage model, int position) {
                // Get references to the views of message.xml
                TextView messageText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.message_text);
                TextView messageUser = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.message_user);
                TextView messageTime = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.message_time);

                // Set their text
                messageText.setText(model.getMessageText());
                messageUser.setText(model.getMessageUser());
                Log.d("getFirebaseMessage", model.getMessageText());

                // Format the date before showing it
                messageTime.setText(DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy (HH:mm:ss)",
                        model.getMessageTime()));
            }

        };
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chat_list, container, false);

        //set OnClick listener for button
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                EditText input = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.input_box);

                // Read the input field and push a new instance
                // of ChatMessage to the Firebase database
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                        .getReference()
                        .child("chats")
                        .push()
                        .setValue(new ChatMessage(input.getText().toString(),
                                FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
                                        .getCurrentUser()
                                        .getDisplayName())
                        );
                Log.d("setFirebaseMessage", input.getText().toString());

                // Clear the input
                input.setText("");
                listOfMessages.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });

        listOfMessages = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_of_messages);

        listOfMessages.setAdapter(adapter);
        listOfMessages.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

**GlobalChat.java**

```
import android.arch.lifecycle.Lifecycle;
import android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner;
import android.arch.lifecycle.OnLifecycleEvent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.hqs.tart.utils.firebase.ui.ChangeEventType;

/**
 * This class is a generic way of backing an Android {@link android.widget.ListView} with a Firebase
 * location. It handles all of the child events at the given Firebase location. It marshals received
 * data into the given class type.
 * <p>
 * See the <a href="https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md">README</a>
 * for an in-depth tutorial on how to set up the FirebaseListAdapter.
 *
 * @param <T> The class type to use as a model for the data contained in the children of the given
 *            Firebase location
 */
public abstract class FirebaseListAdapter<T> extends BaseAdapter implements FirebaseAdapter<T> {
    private static final String TAG = "FirebaseListAdapter";

    private final ObservableSnapshotArray<T> mSnapshots;
    protected final int mLayout;

    public FirebaseListAdapter(FirebaseListOptions<T> options) {
        mSnapshots = options.getSnapshots();
        mLayout = options.getLayout();

        if (options.getOwner() != null) {
            options.getOwner().getLifecycle().addObserver(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START)
    public void startListening() {
        if (!mSnapshots.isListening(this)) {
            mSnapshots.addChangeEventListener(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP)
    public void stopListening() {
        mSnapshots.removeChangeEventListener(this);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY)
    void cleanup(LifecycleOwner source) {
        source.getLifecycle().removeObserver(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(ChangeEventType type,
                               DataSnapshot snapshot,
                               int newIndex,
                               int oldIndex) {
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDataChanged() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(DatabaseError error) {
        Log.w(TAG, error.toException());
    }

    @Override
    public ObservableSnapshotArray<T> getSnapshots() {
        return mSnapshots;
    }

    @Override
    public T getItem(int position) {
        return mSnapshots.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public DatabaseReference getRef(int position) {
        return mSnapshots.getSnapshot(position).getRef();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mSnapshots.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100071/whats-the-purpose-of-item-ids-in-android-listview-adapter
        return mSnapshots.getSnapshot(i).getKey().hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        if (view == null) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(mLayout, viewGroup, false);
        }

        T model = getItem(position);
        Log.d(TAG, "view obtained");
        // Call out to subclass to marshall this model into the provided view
        populateView(view, model, position);
        return view;
    }

    /**
     * Each time the data at the given Firebase location changes, this method will be called for
     * each item that needs to be displayed. The first two arguments correspond to the mLayout and
     * mModelClass given to the constructor of this class. The third argument is the item's position
     * in the list.
     * <p>
     * Your implementation should populate the view using the data contained in the model.
     *
     * @param v        The view to populate
     * @param model    The object containing the data used to populate the view
     * @param position The position in the list of the view being populated
     */
    protected abstract void populateView(View v, T model, int position);
}
```

**FirebaseListAdapter.java**

getView() never called. Can confirm in logcat.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.hqs.tart.fragments.ChatFragment" >

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:tint="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    app:fabSize="mini" />

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/fab"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Input"
        android:id="@+id/input_box"
        />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_above="@id/fab"
    android:dividerHeight="16dp"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:id="@+id/list_of_messages"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**fragment_chat_list.xml**
List layout with button and `edittext`.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/message_user"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/message_user"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:id="@+id/message_time" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/message_user"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/message_text"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**fragment_chat.xml**
Message layout file

I'm certain that I'm not setting the adapter right or something, but I don't know how. Not sure if its the xml either.

```
compileSDK 25
minSDK 19
```

I'm also new to fragments, which might be aiding in this issue.

**EDIT**: Main Activity opens fragment via navigation drawer. Don't know if that'll help.

Comment: So far, I've determined that getCount() is returning 0 and that Firebase is not setup correctly. As to if this particular setup works, I do not know yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final result is that our API was never actually receiving anything from the database. Thusly, this issue. Connected to Firebase through Android Studio and it told us we were missing a key.