# OnItemClickListener for multiple AutoCompleteTextView with switch case not working

Tags: android, xml, switch-statement, autocompletetextview

I have multiple `AutoCompleteTextView` in layout, so i've implemented `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener` globally.

Now issue is that,

i can't compare `AutoCompleteTextView` using `switch` case inside listener,

> **Code**

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.ac_education:
            s_ac_education = testArray[position];
            break;
        case R.id.ac_ethincity:
            s_ac_ethincity = testArray[position];
            break;
        case R.id.ac_languages:
            s_ac_languages = testArray[position];
            break;
        case R.id.ac_location:
            s_ac_location = testArray[position];
            break;
        case R.id.ac_religion:
            s_ac_religion = testArray[position];
            break;
        case R.id.ac_travel:
            s_ac_travel = testArray[position];
            break;
    }
}
```

**Note:** `view.getId()` always returning same value,
i've also tried `if-else` but that doesn't work also.
*(I've already wasted couple of hours)*

**EDIT**

```
private void init(View v) {
    ac_languages = v.findViewById(R.id.ac_languages);
    ac_religion = v.findViewById(R.id.ac_religion);
    ac_location = v.findViewById(R.id.ac_location);
    ac_travel = v.findViewById(R.id.ac_travel);
    ac_ethincity = v.findViewById(R.id.ac_ethincity);
    ac_education = v.findViewById(R.id.ac_education);
    ptr.setACTVAdapter(getActivity(), ac_education, ac_ethincity, ac_languages, ac_location, ac_religion, ac_travel);

    ac_languages.setHint(R.string.languages);

    ac_religion.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    ac_religion.setHint(R.string.religion);

    ac_location.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    ac_location.setHint(R.string.where_do_you_live);

    ac_travel.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    ac_travel.setHint(R.string.where_can_you_travel);

    ac_ethincity.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    ac_ethincity.setHint(R.string.ethincity);

    ac_education.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    ac_education.setHint(R.string.education);
}
```

setAdapter(is defined in another class)

```
public void setACTVAdapter(Activity activity, AutoCompleteTextView... actv) {
    testArray = activity.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.testArray);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(activity, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, testArray);
    for (AutoCompleteTextView ac : actv) {
        ac.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Try this, `switch (parent.getId())` instead of `switch (v.getId())` this.

Comment: @JeelVankhede No, its returns -1.

Comment: Can you please share code where you assign adapter & listeners?

Comment: @JeelVankhede you can check now, i just added more code to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create your custom onItemClickListener:

```
 public class MyClickListener implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    AutoCompleteTextView ac;

    public MyClickListener(AutoCompleteTextView myAc){
        ac = myAc;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        switch(ac.getId()){
            case R.id.autocomplete_1:
                //your code
                break;

            case R.id.autocomplete_2:
                //your code
                break;
        }

    }
}
```

Use it for your AutoCompleteTextView:

```
autoCompleteTextView.setOnItemClickListener(new MyClickListener(autoCompleteTextView));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not rely on view when you're working with a list, specially when you're setting a general item click listener.

Instead get an instance to each view by their id on `public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` method of your `AutoCompleteTextView` adapter and declare a click listener to work with the position you got there, if you want to set multiple click listeners on a row individually.

For example:

```
public class ExampleAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    ...
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView.findViewById(R.id.ac_education);
        v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Your code here
            }
        });
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: AutoCompleteTextView are not list items, those are individually defined in layout using <include /> tag

Comment: Don't you have an adapter to handle suggested item selection? If you don't what's the `OnItemClickListener ` for?

Comment: position of an item is not an issue,
I can't compare view.getId() using AutoCompleteTextView's resource id

Answer (score 0):

According to [official doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html#onItemClick(android.widget.AdapterView%3C?%3E,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20long)) for `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener`,

**`onItemClick()`** method have following parameters,

> **parent:** The AdapterView where the click happened.
>
> **view:** The view within the AdapterView that was clicked (this will be a
>   view provided by the adapter)
>
> **position:** The position of the view in the adapter.
>
> **id:** The row id of the item that was clicked.

So, you might want to use **`parent`** instead of **`view`**, to receive `id` of that parent **`AutoCompleteTextView`**.

*(Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3185328/10271334) answer to get more details.)*

Comment: but it returns -1 while using parent.getId()

Comment: Log.e(TAG, "onItemClick: " + parent.getId() + " -- " + v.getId() + "--" + R.id.ac_education);

Comment: Actually it should work, because official doc also states that.

Comment: Fragment1: onItemClick: -1 -- 16908308--2131361799

Comment: check my log here, parent.getId() is -1

Comment: even v.getId() is same, wherever I'll click.

Answer (score 0):

**It's not the child that you want to track it's clicks, it's convertView.**

So, if you really want to handle child clicks outside of your adapter, you can do like this:

```
public interface OnViewClickListener {
  void onViewClick(View view, int position);
}
```

Then inside of your adapter:

```
private OnViewClickListener mListener;

public void setOnViewClickListener(final OnViewClickListener listener) {
     mListener = listener;
}
```

And for every child you want:

```
child.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v) {
           if (mListener != null) {
              mListener.onViewClick(v, position);
           }
        }
});
```

And with this you can get item clicks:

```
  adapter.setOnViewClickListener(new OnViewClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onViewClick(final View view, final int position) {
        ** PUT YOUR SWITCH CASE HERE! **
     }
  });
```

Comment: i want to write less code, that why i'm using switch case, but your way is too lengthy. because if I''ll implement onItemClickListener on every view, then i can do that very easily.

Comment: @ImranSamed So you cannot just check v.getId() outside of adapter. because its convertView, NOT the child you want. And you get -1 because this view has not ID

Comment: thanks for you time, but i got solution you can check accepted ans

Comment: @ImranSamed is that anything except a custom onClickListener?! By the way happy coding man.

Answer (score 0):

First setup data into Pojo class using array list. And return as string for autotextview. Match that string with arraylist's item value using for loop.

```
autoPartyName.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                            for (CustomersModel list : customersList) {
                                if(list.toString().equals(adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position))){
                                    etContactPhone.setText(list.getContact());
                                    etContactAddress.setText(list.getAddress());
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
```